# Can I make a regex match all characters up to ; except \;?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, message-passing

I am going to construct a message-passing system whose messages have the following structure:

```
message type;message content
```

*(matches `message type;`)*

However, the user can set the message type, and (for the sake of loosely coupled systems) I want to allow them to use a `;` as part of the message type. To do this, I'll have the message constructor escape it with a `\`:

```
tl\;dr;Too long; didn't read content
```

(matches `tl\;dr;`)

**How can I have a regex match all content up to the first `;` that's not `\;`?** In the example, that's the `tl\;dr;` part only. Note that there can be an unescaped `;` within the message content.

I tried `^.*;`, but that matches all content up to a semicolon within the message (e.g. `tl\;dr;Too long;`)

Comment: what flavor of regex? (And most likely can be solved with either a lookahead or look behind)

Comment: Something I can use in Java, Objective C, C#, JavaScript, and PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/.*?[^\\](?=;)/
```

You could also just use `;` instead of `(?=;)`, but the latter prevents it from being part of the full match.

If you only want to match from the start of the string, use:

```
/^.*?[^\\](?=;)/
```

Comment: This matches both `tl\;dr` and `;Too long`.

Comment: @Supuhstar you only have to use the first match; you could also use `^` to anchor the start of the string

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which language are you looking for, but here's the python version regex:

```
^(\\.|[^;])*(?=;)
```

In practice:

```
In [28]: re.search(r'^(\\.|[^;])*(?=;)', r'message type;message content').group(0)
Out[28]: 'message type'

In [37]: re.search(r'^(\\.|[^;])*(?=;)', r"tl\;dr;Too long; didn't read content").group(0)
Out[37]: 'tl\\;dr'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([^;\]|\.)*?;/
```

Depending on your implementation you might need to escape the `\` once or twice. For instance in PHP I'd have to use:

```
/^([^;\\\]|\\\.)*?;/
```

... match all characters not `\\` or `;`, or if you encounter a `\\`, also eat the character right after it regardless of what it is, untill the next character would be `;`

If you want to match *all* parts, this would be what I'd use:

```
/([^;\\\]|\\\.)*?(?=;|$)/
```

Comment: That doesn't validate for me

Comment: Well, those last 2 do for me in PHP. YMMV.